# Windows .exe ridiculously slower than Linux Executable

Tags: c++, linux, windows, performance, visual-studio

So, I'm writing (or have written) a contour mapping application for mapping power frequency in North America, and it works really well... On linux. I run it on a loop to update a bmp map file, which I'm eventually going to output on a website. It can run and update itself in about 3 seconds, which is great for me. The problem came when I tried to port the application to windows. I moved the code into Visual Studios 2012. Linked the libraries, compiled and such, I had to make it ignore a few warnings about float to integer conversion, but I got it working.

Then, I had it run, and it didn't seem to do anything. But, after adding a few output commands, I realized it **was** doing something, it was just doing it probably 100x slower than the Linux executable! I mean, admittedly, the code is pretty intensive (around 400,000 iterations), but this is just ridiculous.

I saw a lot of other topics about VS running slow in debug mode, but even after I compile and run an executable, it's still just as slow.

Here's relevant code, let me know if you have any ideas. Some of the functions you won't recognize because either they aren't relevant to performance (I only call them once, and I know they aren't the source of the speed problem) or they come from the Easy BMP library I'm using for image manipulation. Right now, I have it set to output a 100X100 image, but originally I was outputting a 800x500 pixel image:

```
float get_value(int x, int y, int dataNum, vector<vector<float> > data)
{
    vector<float> distance;
    float value=0; float distanceTotal = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<dataNum; i++)
    {
        distance.push_back(sqrt(pow(data[0][i]-x,2) + pow(data[1][i]-y,2)));
        if(distance[i] < 2)
            return 0;
        distance[i] = 1/pow(distance[i],3);
        distanceTotal+=distance[i];
    }

    for(int i=0; i<dataNum; i++)
    {
        value+=distance[i]/distanceTotal*data[2][i];
    }

    return value;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //set image attributes
    int height=100; int width = 100; int colorScale = 5*255; string dataFile = "data2.txt";

    //get data and colormap
    vector<vector<float> > data = getData(dataFile, width, height);
    vector<RGBApixel> colorMap = makeColorMap(colorScale);
    int dataNum = data[0].size();
    pair<float,float> range = make_pair(*min_element(data[2].begin(),data[2].end()),*max_element(data[2].begin(),data[2].end())); 
    //make image
    BMP newMap;
    newMap.SetBitDepth(16);
    newMap.SetSize(width,height);
        for(int x=0; x<width; x++)
        {
            for(int y=0; y<height; y++)
            {
                        //for debug purposes
                cout << x << " " << y << endl;
                float value = get_value(x,y,dataNum,data);
                            //get color value based on data value
                int colorValue = floor((value-range.first)/(range.second-range.first)*colorScale);
                            //handle border cases
                if(colorValue < 0 )
                    colorValue=0;
                else if(colorValue > colorScale-1)
                    colorValue=colorScale-1;
                newMap.SetPixel(x,y,colorMap[colorValue]);
            }
        }
        newMap.WriteToFile("map.bmp");

    return 0;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you compile in release mode? If the executable isn't compiled in release mode, most optimizations will be turned off.

Comment: Visual Studio has very heavy iterator debugging.  Try `#define _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING 0` and `#define _SECURE_SCL 0`. Also, reserve space in your distance vector before you start your push_back loop at the top of get_value. `vector<float> distance; distance.reserve(dataNum)`.

Comment: Thanks buddy, you're a champ. That cut it down to roughly expected time of ~4 seconds.

Edit: That was directed at Dirk, I didn't see Chris's new comment. I'll try those too to see if I can get things even faster.

Comment: Also, your math can be optimized as well (the way how you calculate `distance` is not optimal).

Comment: ... and you pass `data` array by-value, so it creates (unnecessary) a copy.

Comment: @user2461161: Wait, so you *didn't* compile with optimizations and wondered why it was slow? Are you compiling with optimization for your Linux build?

Comment: STL implementation by Microsoft is suck. If you need the maximum performance in Visual C++, you must use ATL instead.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input. Special shout out to qehgt, the passing by reference solved a big problem I was having. GMan, no, I wasn't compiling with optimization, not to my knowledge at least. Putta, if it comes down to it and it still looks like I need performance gains, I'll look into ATL.

Thanks guys!